# wordpress with cutom login form and custom theme

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, themes, customization

I am printing a custom login form with my custom theme, but when I submit the user credentials, I always get an error - even if they're correct.

Here is my `functions.php`:

```
function rockport_login_fail( $username ) {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
    // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
    if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
        wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );  // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
        exit;
    }
}

function rockport_blank_login() {
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    if ( !strstr($referrer, 'wp-login') ) { // login1 is the name of the loginpage.
        if ( !strstr($referrer, '?login=failed') ) { // make sure we don’t append twice
            wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' ); // let’s append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
        } else {
            wp_redirect( $referrer );
        }
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'authenticate', 'rockport_blank_login');
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'rockport_login_fail' );  // hook failed login
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget to use to check $username. 
[you can also check the complete guide here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-your-own-wordpress-login-page)

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'rockport_login_fail' ); // hook failed login

function rockport_login_fail( $username ) {
  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  // if there’s a valid referrer, and it’s not the default log-in screen
  if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') && $username!=null ) {
    if ( !strstr($referrer, '?login=failed' )) { // make sure we don’t append twice
      wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed'); // let’s append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
    } else {
      wp_redirect( $referrer );
    }
    exit;
  }
}

add_action( 'authenticate', 'rockport_blank_login');

function rockport_blank_login( $username ){
  $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  if ( !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && $username==null ) { // login1 is the name of the loginpage.
    if ( !strstr($referrer, '?login=failed') ) { // make sure we don’t append twice
        wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' ); // let’s append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
      } else {
        wp_redirect( $referrer );
      }
      exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, when i go to standart `wp-login.php` page all works fine

Comment: try this. http://www.inkthemes.com/how-to-redirecting-wordpress-default-login-into-a-custom-login-page/

Comment: no its not necessary. you can add the code in header as per your requirement.

Comment: I dont know what happens, but now it work!! I sure that password was the same! Thanks for help man.